# Is it possible to use the patch utility to delete a file?

Tags: version-control, patch, merge-conflict-resolution

It is well known how to use `patch` to create a new file.
But how to do the opposite: delete an existing file with arbitrary content, or replace it with given content?

Context: suppose there's a directory in the Linux tree with a Makefile and/or Kconfig. I want to build only one custom module (driver) from the assortment they have there, for this I want to add my source file (this is easy) and also replace entire existing Makefile and Kconfig with my content  (only the single line or block for my module).
I want to pack all this into a single patch file.
I don't want to modify the existing files because of high risk of conflicts in surrounding "context".